# GCP - Compute Engine - Putty SSH

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, putty

When I tried to use Putty to generate the key and ssh into VM, I found a weird thing.

I use versions 0.73 and 0.78 to generate a Key respectively. Once generated, I use version 0.73 for SSH into VM. Either 0.73 or 0.78 Key would return an error. When using version 0.78 instead. Whether it is 0.73 or 0.78 Key can be connected normally.

I also tried the 0.76 version, and it works well. I would like to know what is going on with the 0.73 version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is the algorithm support in the SSH client and SSH server. Older SSH clients used RSA+SHA1 which has been deprecated. Newer SSH servers have disabled RSA+SHA1 and enabled RSA+SHA2.

Putty version 0.74 and before do not support RSA+SHA2. If the SSH server has RSA+SHA1 disabled, older putty versions will fail to connect.

Note: The RSA keys did not change, only the algorithms supported.